# Declaratiaion of a variable shared between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

Quite common interview question:
How would you declare a variable in C++ which is to be used by different threads? (or something like..). I thought that 'volatile int x;' is the answer but I see from some comments that this is not correct. I'm interested in both:

- what is the correct answer
- why volatile was thought to be correct (?) in the past but not now..

Comment: `volatile` wasn't right at any time.

Comment: It depends on the requirements of the software, but you can create an atomic variable or depending of the data itself(and the usage) protect it with a mutex.

Answer (score 5):

> what is the correct answer

```
std::atomic<int> x;
```

> why volatile was thought to be correct (?) in the past but not now

It was never correct according to the C++ standard. Before C++11, the standard didn't mention threads at all; C++11 supported synchronisation by adding atomic types (and primitives like `std::mutex`), not by changing the meaning of `volatile` or other existing language features.

One popular compiler decided that `volatile` should cause access to be synchronised across threads, as well as its standard meaning. Other compilers don't provide that extension, so it's not something that you can portably rely on.

Comment: Which compiler was that?

Answer (score 0):

`volatile` was never really the correct answer to this question. The `volatile` keyword provides an indication to the compiler that the variable may change in between uses. Therefore while a multi-threaded application could do this, so could other situations such as port mapped variables on a microcontroller.

Importantly, the compiler would not protect access to the variable, but merely avoid any optimisations which assumed that the variable remained the same between accesses.

For your purposes, `std::atomic<Type>` is a much better answer although it is probably better in an interview situation to understand that the important factor is that inter thread access is controlled by a lock guard, preventing simultaneous read/write or write/write access by different threads.